# Domain redirect to wp-admin/setup-config.php file

Tags: redirect

I have a problem with my WordPress site, it is working well until today.

The problem is when I type my domain name it is redirecting to wp-admin/setup-config.php file. I have no idea why this is happening. The site works fine before.

On domain/wp-admin/setup-config.php page shows a message

> "This page isn’t working www.domain.com is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Are the values for the database in `wp-config.php` correct?  Is the database intact as it was the last time the site worked? if the database has gone AWOL then WP will attempt to run the installer. As to why it is giving a 500 error that is another issue, and may or may not be related.

Comment: @BenCasey I have checked my file structure there is no wp-config.php file. it was automatically deleted. I have no idea how that happened, after that, I make new file and input database credentials, but the site now not loading, not redirecting to wp-admin/setup-config.php file

Comment: Is the site online anywhere we can have a look?

Comment: https://www.boxesfree.com/ it get missing the wp-config.php file. today I have checked my web link, the config file is gone. how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a permission problem. I solved with this commands.

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R * # Let Apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```

Answer (score 0):

I have crossed the same issue.

First, you need to clear your browser cache and deactivate all the plugins related to cache and page preload to your website. Then open your config.php and insert these commands before the line `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Worked for me.